# I need to push extra values into a session

Tags: php

/page1.php/

This is where I get the categories out of the database and put them as checkbox values.

```
$allSubCat = $db->select_where('subCategory', 'catId', $allCats->catId);
    $allSubCatArray = array();
    $d = 0;
    foreach ($allSubCat->result() as $allSubCats){

        $d++;
        echo "

<input name='checkBox[]' type='checkbox' class='' value='" . $allSubCats->subCatName . "'>" . $allSubCats->subCatName . ";
```

/page2.php/

This is where I check if the checkboxes are set, if the checkboxes are set put the value of the checked checkboxes into a $_SESSION['result']. Now if a customer goes back and checks some extra checkboxes the values of these checkboxes new chosen checkboxes replace the already set values in the session. How can I prevent this and add the new chosen values to the already existing ones?

```
    if (isset($_POST['checkBox'])){

   $checkBoxValue = $_POST['checkBox'];
       $session->set('results', $checkBoxValue);
            header('Location: export.php');

    }else if (!$session->exists('results')){

        echo "U heeft geen adviezen gekozen.";

    }else if($session->exists('results')) {

        echo "<b>U heeft de volgende adviezen gekozen: </b><br>";

        $sessionResult = $session->get('results');

    if ($session->exists('results')) {
        $advice = array_push($sessionResult, $checkBoxValue);
    } else if (!$session->exists('results')) {
        $advice = $checkBoxValue;
    }
}
        echo $advice . "<br>";
```

Comment: you'd have to get the existing results array out of the session, amend it, and then put it back in again

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement logic is off.

Inside your first if statement you are always calling session->set(); Instead check inside this if statement that your session['results'] is set. If it isn't then create it. If it is push the values.

Comment: you'r right, my bad. But how do I push the extra set values into the session? Behind the already existing values.

Comment: @yorrid08 just use the array_push function to add the needed values to the array.Unless by saying behind you mean place the new values before the already existing values in the array. If that's what you mean use the array_unshift() function. If this solves your problem mark it as accepted.